# URLSession - Download remote directory

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsurlsession

I am currently using code based on this turtorial http://sweettutos.com/2015/11/06/networking-in-swift-how-to-download-a-file-with-nsurlsession/ to download a remote file using URLSession.downloadTask. This was suprisingly simple. However I would now like to download the entire contents of a remote directory.
Can I use URLSessionDownloadTask or is this only for single files?  If not then how can I obtain a list of the files contained in the remote directory so that I can use downloadTask on each of them individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**First of all you are thinking it in wrong way.**

From the `remote` server, only a `file` that can be `downloaded`(not the folder) and `save` inside the `app`. The file `extension` that you have to download should be `configure` from a server side. Then the `client` side which you can use **Sweettutos** tutorial.

> **First thing you have to do was :**
>
> Talk with the server side developer that he had to zip the remote directory in (.zip or .rar) that you can download it only.

Then, at your code download the url which the server-side given to you and save it in document directory, extract and read the file which you want to.

> **At the URLSession Documentation :**
>
> Download tasks retrieve data in the form of a file, and support
>   background downloads and uploads while the app is not running.

So, there is **no way** you can download **remote directory (unknown file extension)** until you make that remote file available to some file extensions from the server-side.

Comment: Thanks Aung.  just did not cross my mind to zip the directoy up at the server end.